# R interface to Gecode (open source constraint programming toolkit)

Tags: r, gecode

I'd like to use the open-source Gecode (gecode.org) framework for constraint programming within R. So far I did not found any direct route. I found lots of bindings and interfaces to Ruby, Python, Prolog but not a direct one for R.

Any pointer to a library or other means how to use Gecode within a typical R project would be highly appreciated.